# asp.net mvc - Rewrite Url after return view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting

I have a problem like this. In RouteConfig.cs, I set routes

```
routes.MapRoute(
      "NewsDetails",
      "news/details-news/{title}-{id}",
      new { controller = "News", action = "Details", id = "", title = "" }
);
```

In my Index.cshtml of NewsController I have a link

```
@Html.RouteLink(item.Title, "NewsDetails", new { 
         title = MyWeb.Classes.PrettyUrlHelper.PrettyUrl(item.Title), 
         id = item.Id 
})
```

In my NewsController:

```
public ActionResult Details(string title,String id)
{
    if (id == null && title == null)
       return RedirectToAction("Index");


     try
     {
        int ID = Int32.Parse(id);

        var result = NewsConnectionDB.GetInstance().Single<LifeStory>(ID);

        return View(result);
      }

      catch (InvalidOperationException) { 
          return  View("~/Views/Error/Error404.cshtml"); 
      }
      catch (FormatException) { 
          return View("~/Views/Error/Error404.cshtml"); }
 }
```

So if a user click on link in View, that link will route to action Details to process, and the link is Seo Url Friendly (localhost:9224/news/details-news/ten-things-2). But a user types a link instead of clicking to a link in View:

```
  localhost:9224/news/details-news/ten-thingsblahblahblah-2
```

The url above is correct with id but title is not. So how can I update the url after I return View if a user types the wrong title but right id?

Any help would be appreciated.

P/S: my English is not good, so I hope you understand it.

Comment: In controller, rewrite this URL with code **HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("CorrectUrl", "YourUrl");**

Answer (score 0):

If title is incorrect then you can send correct url in response headers. If it's ajax call then on completion check for correct url in response header. If correct url exists then change your browser url using  `window.history.pushState` javascript method.

In *Details* action method use below code to set response header.

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("CorrectUrl", "YourUrl");
```

Comment: it does'nt work, i have try HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Length", String.Format("/news/details-news/{0}-{1}", result.Title, result.Id)); but everything does not happen. If i try return Redirect( String.Format("/news/details-news/{0}-{1}"", result.Title, result.Id)); that will re-query to database again, it's not good the way to do, am i right?

Answer (score 0):

Use **HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode(string);**

javascript code can be replace url, I think it will be working :).

C# code

```
string _entitle = HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode(_strTitle);
string _strCorUrl = "http://example.com/"+ _entitle + "-" + _intID.toString();
```

script code

```
top.window.location.replace('CorrectUrl');
```

or C# code redirect url

```
Response.Redirect(url);
```

**Update**
possible 1 solution with **Context.RewritePath**

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa5wkk6d(v=vs.110).aspx

```
void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string originalPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path.ToLower();
    if (originalPath.Contains("/page1"))
    {
        Context.RewritePath(originalPath.Replace("/page1", "/RewritePath.aspx?page=page1"));
    }
    if (originalPath.Contains("/page2"))
    {
        Context.RewritePath(originalPath.Replace("/page2", "/RewritePath.aspx"), "pathinfo", "page=page2");
    }
}
```

It code is example, You can use it
I hope it help

Comment: thanks for help, script code doesn't work but C# Redirect url does. If i use Redirect that will redirect action Details again so i have to re-query database again, is that way good way to do?

Comment: i try to update your answer but it doesn't anything happen, so i have to use Redirect method and some static variables to prevent re-query database again. Thanks for all your help and supported me.

Comment: =)). are you tried yet?. and apply **RewritePath** to your application?.

in controller you can redirect to another URL begin query database :). If you check current URL is wrong begin query database and return to view.

And if my answer helped, can you vote up it. for another user can view and get my answer for them.

Comment: of course, i had tried it, why do you think don't do it?. If i use RewritePath, the Path is modified, but when return View, my URL is incorrect so i told you it's not anything happen. And how can i check if current URL is correct  when i don't query to database and return View?. Your answer is right and helpful however it doesn't help in my problem. Thanks you very much.

Comment: Of course, you mush query to database check **title** is true, if you don't query database, how you can check **title** is true. My answer help you change your URL. **the Path is modified, my URL is incorrect ** why you tell me nothing happen?. your problem had solved **So how can I update the url after I return View if a user types the wrong title but right id?**

Comment: oh sorry, **the Path** i told you it is the property in **HttpContext.Request**, it's changed but in client-side the url don't change .. However your answer helpful me so now we don't argue each other more. Tks you!